# How do I load and decrypt an encrypted key file for a cert in Go?

Tags: go, x509certificate

I have a cert file and a key file where the key file is encrypted with a password. I am trying to decrypt the key file programmatically before loading the key pair.

```
// Key file and cert file path
cf := filepath.Join(certPath, certFile)
kf := filepath.Join(certPath, keyFile)

//Read & decode the encrypted key file with the pass to make tls work
keyIn, err := ioutil.ReadFile(kf)
if err != nil {
    log.Error("Read key error", err)
    return nil, err
}

// Decode and decrypt our PEM block
decodedPEM, _ := pem.Decode([]byte(keyIn))
decrypedPemBlock, err := x509.DecryptPEMBlock(decodedPEM, []byte("somepassword"))
if err != nil {
    log.Error("decrypt key error", err)
    return nil, err
}

// Load our decrypted key pair
crt, err := tls.LoadX509KeyPair(cf, string(decrypedPemBlock))
if err != nil {
    log.Error("load key pair error", err)
    return nil, err
}
```

The original certs and key were generated using the following openssl parameters

```
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -x509 -keyout $CA_CERT.key -out $CA_CERT -days $validity -passin "pass:$password" -passout "pass:$password" -subj "/C=$C/ST=$ST/L=$L/O=$O/CN=$CN/emailAddress=$EMAIL"
```

The variables are substituted accordingly with $password being "somepassword"

I have tried decrypting the key using `openssl rsa` from the command line and it works fine with the the password above.

However in Go I get an error in `tls.LoadX509KeyPair` saying invalid argument.

```
time="2018-01-17T18:57:40Z" level=error msg="load key pair error: open
```

My best guess is that the key encoding might be messed up and I was wondering if anything is wrong with my code.

Update: Added error message and it seems like `tls.LoadX509KeyPair` can't understand the format as comments have pointed out below.

Comment: Please paste the actual error output into the question body.

Comment: [LoadX509KeyPair](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/tls/#LoadX509KeyPair) takes filenames to read from, not file contents. Also, it wants PEM-encoded file contents, but `DecryptPEMBlock` returns a DER-encoded key. I think you'll have to modify [X509KeyPair](https://golang.org/src/crypto/tls/tls.go?s=5915:5986#L183) yourself.

Comment: The x509.Parse*PrivateKey and x509.ParseCertificate functions can load DER bytes.

Comment: @Peter Should I use `x509.ParsePKCS8PrivateKey()` or `x509.ParsePKCS1PrivateKey()` ?

Comment: @dikshant, well, that depends on your key, of course. If you don't know in advance, try both and see which one produces an error. This is also what the tls package does: https://golang.org/src/crypto/tls/tls.go?#L280